# swift: how to pass JSON to secondViewController

Tags: json, swift2

I want to pass the JSON data to MainMenuPageViewController.

MainMenuPageViewController UILabel(UsernameLabel)

Thank you

Picture1:
[image]

```
let jsonUserId: String = json["return"] as! String
if (jsonUserId != "0") {
    print("username and password correct")
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainMenuPageViewController")
    self.showViewController(vc, sender: self)
    //pass the jsonUserId to MainMenuPageViewController
    //MainMenuPageViewController has UILabel(UserIdLabel)
    })
}
```

---

[image]

If I input wrong username and password, system will run to line 57 but the alert will error, when I input long String(a,A,@,etc.). However, if I input shot String(shing, herry,123,etc.) app can display the alert message.
Also, if input the space bar and (!@#$%^&*()_+). it will error.
Can you help me to fix this error? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare variable in MainMenuPageViewController like

```
class MainMenuPageViewController: UIViewController {

var UserIdLabel = String()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
}
```

and for pass data

```
  let jsonUserId: String = json["return"] as! String
 if (jsonUserId != "0") {
    print("username and password correct")
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        if let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainMenuPageViewController") as? MainMenuPageViewController {
           vc.UserIdLabel = jsonUserId
           self.showViewController(vc, sender: self)
        } 
     })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a property in the `MainMenuPageViewController` to store the user id and then in viewDidLoad set the `UsernameLabel` text to the stored property.

var userID:String! //define this in the MainMenuPageViewController

Then after you create the vc set the userID property to the jsonUserID

`if let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainMenuPageViewController") as? MainMenuPageViewController {
    vc.userID = jsonUserId
    self.showViewController(vc, sender: self)
} else {
    printf("The VC is not of the right type")
}`

`override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    UsernameLabel.text = userID
}`